# What's the minimum number of weighs required for finding the different weight ball?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

If there are 9 balls among which if 1 ball is of different weight, it requires minimum of 2 weighs to find the odd ball.
  If there are 27 balls, it requires 3 chances.

> 9 -> 3 pow 2 -> 2 chances.
>
> 27 -> 3 pow 3 -> 3 chances.

Question: Whats the minimum number of weighs required for finding the odd ball if given

> 3 pow 45 - 3 pow 40 balls

?

Can't use calculator. I think, some equation/formula need to be derived.

Can anybody crack this puzzle?

Comment: The close votes are not due do duplication, but because your question is off topic, since it is not directly related to programming. You may have more luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `3^x = N` balls and `x -- number of weighs`, `x = log3(N)`;

```
3^x = 3^45 - 3^40;
3^x = 3^40 * (3^5 - 1);
x = log3(3^40) + log3(3^5 - 1) = 40 + log3(242);
real_x = ceil(x);
```

Comment: Mmm, the first assumption is real according to that 3^2 -> 2 and 3^3 -> 3, prove me wrong. If so, x(N) = log3(N) function. And there is no need to compute x(a^alpha - b^beta), because if beta is less than alpha, b^beta = o(a^alpha), so we can drop it. And ofc I can do a mistake.

Comment: To finish: 4 = log(3^4) < log(3^5-1) < log(3^5) = 5 so ceil(log(3^5-1))=5, so the result is 45.

Comment: +1: Perfect. Thank you. Thanks to sdcwc as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another intuitive way to derive the answer is by asking yourself this question:

How many balls can be checked at most by a single weighting?

The answer is 3. The reason is because if you compare two balls out of 3, you either find the one of different weight immediately (whether heavier or lighter) or you find that they are of equal weight which by process of elimination leads to the third ball being of a different weight.

As a result one can divide N balls over groups of 3 plus a remainder group of M (with 0<=M<3). Apply a single such weighting per group of 3 will eliminate 2/3rds of all balls. This means you are left with a new group of balls from which you need to find the one with different weight, the number of balls in this group is equal to floor(N/3) + M.

By applying the same procedure to this reduced group of balls, you can find the ball with different weight in the general case in at most ceiling(log(N)/log(3)) steps. The reason for the ceiling() statement is that you may eventually run out of groups of 3 and be left with a group of 2 balls for which 1 additional weighting is required. (If the last group is only 1 ball you need not weigh it to deduce it must be the one ball of different weight. More precisely formulated the number of weightings required appearst to be at most floor(log(N)/log(3)) + 1; from there the simple observation that if log(N)/log(3) is integer the 1 additional weighting is not required leads to the more precise value of ceiling(log(N)/log(3)).)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, we have to infer that the different-weight ball is either known to be heavier or known to be lighter.  For simplicity I'll assume it's heavier.

First let's see why it's possible to do this in 45 weighings:  For 3n balls, one can weigh n versus n, leaving n unweighed, and reduce to n balls.  Do this 40 times, reducing to a batch of (3^45-3^40)/3^40 = 3^5-1 = 242 balls.  The heavy ball is somewhere in there.  Add a known normal ball, so you have 243 (a power of 3 again) and continue with five more weighings, after which you'll have the heavy ball.

Next let's see why it can't be done in 44 weighings or fewer:  Each weighing provides you with one piece of information, which can be thought of as a number 0, 1, or 2.  0 for "the heavy ball is on the left", 1 for "the heavy ball is on the right", and 2 for "the heavy ball is in the unweighed batch."  This is true no matter how many balls are weighed against an equal number of balls.  Thus the results of any 44 weighings can be regarded as a sequence of 44 digits -- 0's, 1', and 2's.  There are 3^44 possible results of *any* strategy using 44 weighings.  But you have more than 3^44 balls, so you cannot guarantee to find the right one using an experimental process which produces only 3^44 different answers.  From the point of view of information theory, there is more information in the "right answer" than can be produced by 44 weighings.

Comment: We do not have to infer anything when using the traditional weighing method of the scales, btw.